# Why stand for responsive T'hilim?

Tags: tehilim-psalms, standing-sitting

For many a distressful situation (that should not come!), people organize a communal recitation of parts of the book of *T'hilim* (Psalms). In some of these, there is a leader, who recites each verse and is copied by the assembled; he then recites the next, and so on. Almost invariably in my experience, the entire group of people (except the lame and the weak) is standing throughout. Why do they stand? I'd appreciate learning any reason for doing so or, especially, any source that says they should or that says that it's customary for them to do so.

Comment: similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26625/759 People tend to stand for not so common prayers with whose messages they can directly associate because they seem more important to them, it seems to me.

Comment: Yeah, this definitely reminded me of my question, and so far I'm left to conclude similarly to @Double AA.